# How to create a dynamic where clause in oracle

Tags: oracle11g

My requirement is to create a procedure or SQL query in which where clause should be created in run time depending on the paramters provided by the user.

Example if user provides data for three columns then where clause should have filter conditions for these three columns only to select the data from database table, like wise if user provides data for 4 columns then where caluse should have 4 columns.

Comment: Have you tried anything yet?

Comment: try http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/dynamic.htm#LNPLS011

Comment: "if user provides data for three columns"..ambiguous..What dies this mean.. How can an user provide data for 3 columns.

Comment: we will be getting input from the webservices, but concern here is not how the user will provide input, challenge is how to write where clause dynamically at run time. Example: Consider employe table with 5 columns as Emp Id , Frst name, Lst Name, Addrss, Phn Num. Now we need a sql which can provide data from emp table per below scenarios:

Comment: case 1: Select * from EMP where emp_id =1234 and Addrss ='xyz' and Lst_name ='abc'
case 2 : Select * from EMP where frst_nm ='John' and PHN_num= 1234355 and Lst_name ='abc'
like wise other cases for other filters in where clause, that all to be added depending on what type of information user has provided to search on

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any very specific solution to your question but it can be done using putting OR in where clause with different set of user input. See below:

Created procedure: Here my employee table has emp_id,name and salary columns. Now am assuming user sometimes passes `emp_id` and `emp_name` alone.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE dynmc_selec (id                  NUMBER DEFAULT 0,
                                         name                VARCHAR2 DEFAULT 'A',
                                         salary              NUMBER DEFAULT 0,
                                         emp_output   IN OUT SYS_REFCURSOR)
AS
   var   VARCHAR2 (100);
BEGIN
   --You need to make several combinations in where clause like ( emp_id , emp_name , salary ) OR ( emp_id , emp_name ) OR (emp_name , salary ) and use it in where clause with 'OR'.
   --Also its needed that all the columns of the table is in where clause. If user doesnot pass anything then defualt value will be passed.
   var :=
         'select emp_id from employee where ( emp_id ='
      || id
      || '  and  emp_name = '''
      || name
      || ''' ) OR emp_sal = '
      || salary;

   DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line (var);

   EXECUTE IMMEDIATE var;

   OPEN emp_output FOR var;
EXCEPTION
   WHEN OTHERS
   THEN
      NULL;
END;
```

Calling it:

```
declare
a  SYS_REFCURSOR;

v_emp_id  employee.emp_id%type;

begin
 --passing emp_id and name only
 dynmc_selec(id=>1,name=>'KING',emp_output=>a);

  loop
    FETCH a INTO v_emp_id;
        EXIT WHEN a%NOTFOUND;
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(v_emp_id );

  end loop;

end;
```

Output:

```
select emp_id from employee where ( emp_id =1  and  emp_name = 'KING' ) OR emp_sal = 0
1
```

Answer (score 0):

```sql
select * from test_table
where 
  (1 = nvl2(:l_date, 0, 1) or created_at > :l_date)
  and (1 = nvl2(:l_no, 0,1) or no = :l_no);
```

With Oracle `nvl2` function:
When the parameter `l_date` is null, then `1 = nvl2(l_date, 0, 1)` evaluates to true and the filter by `created_at` is not taking place.
When the parameter `l_date` is not null, then `1 = nvl2(l_date, 0, 1)` evaluates to false and the filter by `created_at` is taking place.
The same thing happens with the parameter `l_no`.